# I don't understand the following C code line

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-operators

I found the following thread:
[Calculate broadcast address from ip and subnet mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777617/calculate-broadcast-address-from-ip-and-subnet-mask) and there the link to http://lpccomp.bc.ca/netmask/netmask.c

Could someone please explain the following line, I don't understand:

```
for ( maskbits=32 ; (mask & (1L<<(32-maskbits))) == 0 ; maskbits-- )
```

especially `mask & (1L<<(32-maskbits))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<<` is the [bitwise left shift operator](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/); it shifts the bits of a value left by the given amount. Thus `1L<<(32-maskbits)` shifts the value 1 to the left `32-maskbits` times.

`&` is the [bitwise AND operator](http://cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/).

So the loop expression `mask & (1L<<(32-maskbits)) == 0` tests all the bits within the value of `mask`, from lower to higher. The loop will stop on the first (lowest) nonzero bit of `mask`, at which point `maskbits` will contain the number of bits above (and including) that bit.

E.g.

- if <strike>`mask == 0xFFFF`</strike> `mask == 0xFFFFFFFF (== binary 11111111111111111111111111111111)`, the loop will stop on the first iteration, and `maskbits` will be 32
- if <strike>`mask == 0x0001`</strike> `mask == 0x00000001 (== binary 00000000000000000000000000000001)`, the loop will again stop on the first iteration, and `maskbits` will be 32
- if <strike>`mask == 0x1000`</strike> `mask == 0x01000000 (== binary 00000001000000000000000000000000)`, the loop will stop on the 24th iteration, and `maskbits` will be 8

Comment: question: I get the bitwise AND operation to check when to stop the bits counting, I don't get why using the left shifting with a long int. `1` was not enough?

Comment: @dierre, to avoid integer overflow. On some platforms an `int` is only 16 bits long, where if you left shift any `int` value by more than 16, the result is undefined (can be 0). Declaring the value as `long` ensures it is at least 32 bits long.

Comment: one more question: I am a bit confused about the "1L" statement. What is it exactly?

Comment: @mspoerr: it's a long int. Read above Peter's comment.

Comment: Peter are you sure the last example is correct? `0x1000` shouldn't give `maskbits=20`?

Comment: @dierre, oops, right. The 4-digit hex values represented only 16 bits. Fixed, thanks :-)

Comment: @mspoerr: I wrote an example. Maybe it could help you.
@Peter Torok: np.

Comment: Shift of signed values is tricky and can lead to undefined behavior. In the example if `long` has width 32, for the value of `maskbits` being 1 the shift reads `1L << 31` which may be UB. So here the`1L` should be replaced at least with a `1UL` to obtain an `unsigned long` value for the mask. Even better would be to use `UINT32_C(1)` for it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at bitwise operators, specifically left shift.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B_and_Java

Answer (score 1):

To see what's happening: run it.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char *binary (unsigned int v) {
static char binstr[33] ;
int i ;

binstr[32] = '\0' ;
for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
binstr[31-i] = v & 1 ? '1' : '0' ;
v = v / 2 ;
}

return binstr ;
}

int main(void){  

  unsigned long maskbits,mask;  

mask = 0x01000000;
cout << "MASK IS: " << binary(mask) << "\n";
cout << "32 is: " << binary(32) << "\n\n";
for ( maskbits=32 ; (mask & (1L<<(32-maskbits))) == 0 ; maskbits-- ) {
cout << "maskbits: " << binary(maskbits) << "\n";
cout << "\t(32-maskbits): " << binary((32-maskbits)) << "\n";
cout << "\t1L<<(32-maskbits): " << binary((1L<<(32-maskbits))) << "\n";
cout << "\t(mask & (1L<<(32-maskbits))): " << binary((mask & (1L<<(32-maskbits)))) << "\n\n";

}

cout << "\nFinal maskbits: " << maskbits;

return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/eB8Kp