# How can I determine Network IP, Gateway and Broadcast IP from IP address and Subnet?

Tags: ip, ip-address, gateway, subnet

I have an IP address 10.1.0.4

and subnet 129

How can I determine Network IP, Gateway and Broadcast IP?

Comment: What platform? And manually, or programmatically? This question should be clarified or moved or closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't determine the gateway, your ISP or sysadmin should have told you what gateway to use.

I don't know what you mean by "Network IP"; you IP address **is** a network IP address.

The broadcast depends on the network mask, it's the mask with the trailing zeroes replaced by ones.

Comment: thank you. But the thing is I have to calculate it manually. 

The ip address is 10.1.0.4 and Subnet is /29 

what is the broadcast IP ?

Comment: The gateway can be any arbitrarily defined IP address that the sysadmin chose at his own whim the day he set the network up, theres *no way* to know which one it is (other than trying the entire /29 block).

Comment: As for the broadcast address, this may help further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777617/calculate-broadcast-address-from-ip-and-subnet-mask