# UDP broadcast on machine with multiple network adapters on Windows with native C++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming, udp

I need to do UDP broadcast (I recognize this should ideally be multicast instead) on a Windows machine with multiple network adapters using native C++ code.

Currently, I'm setting the SO_BROADCAST socket option on the socket to allow broadcast and am then sending to the INADDR_BROADCAST address (255.255.255.255).  This doesn't reliably work on a machine with multiple network adapters.

I've been searching around and found tons of questions about this on Stack Overflow.  From what I can tell, the best approach seems to be to figure out the broadcast IP for each  network adapter and then loop over those sending to each one.

So, for example, if my machine has a network adapter with a 10.0.0.x IP address and another one with a 192.168.1.x, then I need to send the message to 10.0.0.255 and 192.168.1.255.

Despite all the questions/answers I've looked through, I haven't been able to connect the dots to get the above list of addresses.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  For example, I found some sample code for using GetAdaptersAddresses to enumerate the IP addresses, but I don't see where you can get the subnet mask for each address.  Without the subnet mask I can't determine the broadcast address.  I need the list of IP addresses, and the subnet mask for each one so I can form the list of broadcast addresses to send to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API call GetAdaptersInfo fills a IP_ADAPTER_INFO struct for each network adapter. According to the documentation the mask is provided in the list of addresses:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

you can calculate the broadcast address once you have the IP address and mask:

[Calculate broadcast address from ip and subnet mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777617/calculate-broadcast-address-from-ip-and-subnet-mask)

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I noticed though that there's a comment in the docs indicating that, "On Windows XP and later:  Use the GetAdaptersAddresses function instead of GetAdaptersInfo.".  When I looked there I didn't see where to get the subnet mask, though, maybe its the same thing where its returned in the list of addresses.

Comment: Looks like this might not work on Windows 8.  It does work fine on Windows 7 though.

Comment: Unlike `GetAdaptersInfo()`, `GetAdaptersAddresses()` does not directly provide subnet masks. However, if you include the `GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX` flag, you can use the provided list of prefixes to calculate the subnet mask and even the broadcast IP.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `GetIpAddrTable()` and match up the IPs from the `GetAdaptersAddresses()` output to find the subnet masks. IPs and prefixes are not listed in a 1-to-1 matchup in the `GetAdaptersAddresses()` output, so it takes a little work to match them up as-is.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `GetUnicastIpAddressTable()`, which includes prefix lengths with each IP, so you can calculate the subnet for each one.

Comment: From what I can tell, GetAdaptersAddresses() can only be used to get the subnet mask in Vista and later by calling ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask(pAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress->OnLinkPrefixLength, &myULongSubnetMask); where pAddresses is the buffer returned by GetAdaptersAddresses().  Before Vista, OnLinkPrefixLength is not defined.  Further, you can only calculate the broadcast address if you know the subnet mask.

Answer (score 2):

RichardBrock's answer was correct, the GetAdaptersInfo gives the needed info.  Here's some code showing more specifically how to do this.  Note that this code uses MFC and a string conversion macro, STR_A2T which just converts from the char* string to the wchar_t* string as the project is built for Unicode.  The result is an array of strings, where each one is a broadcast IP.  Then we just loop through those and send to each one.

```
CStringArray baList;
baList.RemoveAll();

ULONG bufSz = 0;
if (GetAdaptersInfo(NULL,&bufSz) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
{
    vector<BYTE> buf;
    buf.resize(bufSz,0);
    if (GetAdaptersInfo((IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)&buf[0],&bufSz) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        IP_ADAPTER_INFO* pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)&buf[0];
        for(; pAdapterInfo != NULL; pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next)
        {
            unsigned long ip = inet_addr(pAdapterInfo->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);
            unsigned long mask = inet_addr(pAdapterInfo->IpAddressList.IpMask.String);
            unsigned long bcip = ip | ~mask;
            struct in_addr ia;
            ia.S_un.S_addr = bcip;
            CString broadcastAddr;
            STR_A2T(inet_ntoa(ia),broadcastAddr);
            baList.Add(broadcastAddr);
        }
    }
}
```